# How to direct a custom domain at a particular tweet

Tags: domain-name-system, redirect, rewrite, url

I have registered a new domain, let's call it `particulartweet.com`.

I would like users who enter that domain in their browser to land on a particular Twitter URL, like https://twitter.com/wgervais/status/1260723066847391747.

Can I do this just with DNS record settings? Or do I need to set up a simple web server to do the redirect for me?

I have full control over the DNS settings - but would prefer not to have to set up a server. Keep things as simple as possible.

I searched other SO answers, but couldn't figure out whether this was possible or not.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [DNS - Redirect from old server to new](https://serverfault.com/questions/245988/dns-redirect-from-old-server-to-new)

Comment: No @GeraldSchneider, I'm aware of that question and it doesn't answer mine.
The use case is different, and the solutions offered there are thus different. This is not a good answer to this question: _You can use a 301 redirect on your old server to point at your new one. There's no way to do this in DNS, but it will ensure that all traffic reaches the intended destination while your old records are still cached elsewhere._

Comment: That's exactly the answer to your question. It's not possible to do this with DNS only.

Comment: But the question is asked in a very convoluted way with caveats, edits etc.
I'd appreciate a clear answer suited to this question. Can I for example point it at Twitter name servers? So that it would go to Twitter.com but then the query would be lost? That's what I think, but I'm not sure.
Also the caching part is entirely irrelevant here.

Comment: "I'd appreciate a clear answer suited to this question." **NO** you can't do what you describe just with the DNS, which maps **names** (not URLs) to IP addresses here. You need the DNS to point the hostname to a webserver and then you need to configure that webserver to reply for this hostname and do a proxy or redirect to the real URL.

Comment: "Can I for example point it at Twitter name servers?".  **NO**. Twitter (or anyone else) nameservers are irrelevant here.

Answer (score 1):

*Answer created from @Patrick-Mevzek's helpful comments:*

NO you can't do what you describe just with the DNS, which maps names (not URLs) to IP addresses here. You need the DNS to point the hostname to a webserver and then you need to configure that webserver to reply for this hostname and do a proxy or redirect to the real URL.

*"Can I for example point it at Twitter name servers?".*

NO. Twitter (or anyone else) nameservers are irrelevant here.